# Weird black rectangle on pygame window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a 2d super mario bros in pygame, but when I open up the window, there is a gigantic black rectangle positioned in the top-left corner of the screen, here is the screenshot:
[image]

Does anybody know what this black rectangle is? Here is my main.py:

```
#-- TODO
# * 

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from mario import Mario
from levels import *
import os

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(r'./themesong.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

monitorInfo = pygame.display.Info()
W, H = monitorInfo.current_w, monitorInfo.current_h

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption('Super Mario Bros by WinstonMan')

current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
BACKGROUND = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(current_path, 'background.png')), (W, H))
BLOCK = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(current_path, 'block.png')), (100, 100))



def main():
    level = 1
    running = True
    FPS = 120
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    right = False
    left = False
    jumping = False
    jumpcount = 0

    mario = Mario(100, H - 100, 100, 100)

    def redrawWindow():
        wn.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))


        mario.draw(wn)

    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

        redrawWindow()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            right = True
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            left = True
        if keys[K_UP]:
            jumping = True
        
        if not keys[K_RIGHT]:
            right = False

        if not keys[K_LEFT]:
            left = False
        
        if not keys[K_UP]:
            jumping = False
        
        if right:
            mario.moveright()
            if mario.x + mario.width > W:
                mario.x = W - mario.width
        
        if left:
            mario.moveleft()
            if mario.x < 0:
                mario.x = 0
        
        if jumping:
            if jumpcount < 2:
                mario.grav = -10
                mario.y += mario.grav
            jumpcount += 1
        
        if mario.y < H - 200:
            mario.y += mario.grav
            mario.grav += 1
        
        if mario.y > H - 200:
            mario.y = H - 200
            jumpcount = 0
        
        # mario.updateY(H)
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my mario.py:

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

class Mario:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.big_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('./', 'mario_big.png')), (self.width, self.height))
        self.small_img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('./', 'mario_small.png')), (self.height - 50, self.height - 50))
        self.grav = 0
        self.x_vel = 7
        self.X_MAX_VEL = 7
        self.X_MIN_VEL = -7
        self.img = self.small_img
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)
        # self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
        

    def jump(self):
        self.grav = -10

    def moveright(self):
        self.x += self.x_vel

    def moveleft(self):
        self.x -= self.x_vel
    
    def deccelerate(self):
        if self.x_vel > 0:
            self.x_vel -= 1
        elif self.x_vel < 0:
            self.x_vel += 1
    
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
```

And finally, my levels.py:

```
import pygame, os

class Level1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blockcoords = []
```

I am on a Windows 10 computer with python version 3.8.3 and pygame version 1.9.6.

Comment: How do you update your window? do you use pygame.display.flip() or pygame.display.update() and if you use update what parameters do you pass through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to update the window by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) in `redrawWindow`:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    def redrawWindow():
        wn.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))

        mario.draw(wn)

        pygame.display.flip() # <--- this is missing

    # [...]
```

Comment: ah, yes, I thought it would be a face palm error, thanks